# TextArea.continueCursor(TextArea.java:331) / ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16

Tags: user-interface, libgdx, thread-safety, indexoutofboundsexception

What could be the cause of this error? (Can't figure it out)

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextArea.continueCursor(TextArea.java:331)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextArea.calculateOffsets(TextArea.java:278)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField.draw(TextField.java:283)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.drawChildren(Group.java:124)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.draw(Group.java:58)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.WidgetGroup.draw(WidgetGroup.java:154)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table.draw(Table.java:123)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.drawChildren(Group.java:111)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.draw(Group.java:58)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.draw(Stage.java:128)
at se.scapegoat.channelsclient.screens.AbstractScreen.render(AbstractScreen.java:36)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Is this due to thread-safety issue possibly -Can I not set text from wherever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely to be a threading issue as you suggest.

The code referenced by your stacktrace is looping through every character in the string. If you changed the string to a shorter one in the middle of the loop it would cause exactly this sort of issue.

One way around this would be to run your text-changing code using `Application.postRunnable()`

LibGdx is not inherently thread-safe, and whilst it's possible to write threaded code that uses it, you have to be careful about what happens on what threads.

There's some information on libgdx threading [on this page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading).

Comment: OK thx! But it seems really crazy that I should have to post a Runnable each time I only would like to change a simple text in a ui textfield!!! Is it really the way to go?

Comment: In the normal run of things you wouldn't have to, however as you're program needs to use threading, you have to go through a few hoops.